# Как скачать zip архив с помощью googledriveapi и java?

Tags: java, javafx, google-drive

Как скачать zip архив с помощью googledriveapi и java? Там написано не очень много, что такое driveService? И что нужно в него передавать?

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, вы уже успешно запускали пример [Drive API Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java)
(если нет, то выполните все действия в нём по порядку и запустите приложение - туториал достаточно прозрачный).
Объект service (класса Drive) как раз создается в примере в этом туториале.

После успешного запуска приложения и выдачи разрешения на просмотр данных оно выводит список файлов на вашем гугл диске.

Чтобы иметь возможность скачивать zip архив, нужно немного модифицировать данный пример:

1. Добавить в область действия приложения значения `DRIVE`, `DRIVE_FILE` и `DRIVE_APPDATA`

```java
    private static List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();

    static
    {
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
    }
```

2. В объект класса Drive нужно передать ID того файла на гугл диске, который вы хотите скачать. Поэтому сначала нужно найти данный файл и получить его ID:

```
String desiredFileName = "file.zip";
List<File> files = result.getFiles();
File f = files.stream().filter(file -> file.getName().equals(desiredFileName)).findFirst().orElse(null);
String fileId = f.getId();
```

3. Скачать файл на локальный диск (допустим, в корень диска D: с тем же именем `file.zip`):

```java
 OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("D:\\file.zip"));
            service.files().get(fileId)
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
```

4. Перед новым запуском приложения нужно удалить папку `tokens` из корня проекта и выдать приложению разрешения заново во время следующего запуска.

Полный пример кода:

```html
package gdrivezip;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/* class to demonstarte use of Drive files list API */
public class DownloadZip {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Drive API Java Quickstart";
    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    /** Directory to store authorization tokens for this application. */
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();

    static
    {
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
    }

    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DownloadZip.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        //returns an authorized Credential object.
        return credential;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();

        String desiredFileName = "file.zip";

        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            File f = files.stream().filter(file -> file.getName().equals(desiredFileName)).findFirst().orElse(null);
            String fileId = f.getId();
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File("D:\\file.zip"));
            service.files().get(fileId)
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```